# execute R script from php

Tags: php, r

I am trying to execute R script from Php. It works fine with the command prompt with this :

```
 Documents\R\R-3.5.0\bin\R.exe Desktop\my_script.R
```

But the same is not working from PHP call using exec. Any suggestion please!

```
<?php 
   exec("Documents\R\R-3.5.0\bin\R.exe Desktop\my_script.R", $output);
   print_r($output);
?>
```

`print_r($output)` displays only `"Array()"` no correct result ;

Comment: try `C:\Users\UserName\Documents` ... etc.

Comment: Hi @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, I tried it already, no luck,

Comment: place `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` before the `exec()` and see if it outputs any errors

Comment: Thanks! I get an error saying "The system cannot find the path specified." I am using this below
C\Users\"myName"\Documents\R\R-3.5.0\bin\R.exe Desktop\my_script.R
may be it might need pwd? same path is what I am getting a result in cmd prompt

Comment: not sure with Windows machines ... see if it works if the .R script is in the same place as the exec script (and change path accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those paths must be relative to the php working directory. Otherwise they must be fully specified:

Try:

```
$cmd = "C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\R\R-3.5.0\bin\Rscript.exe C:\Users\YOURNAME\Desktop\my_script.R";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Comment: I get this error with the proper path now: Array ( [0] => ARGUMENT 'Desktop\my_script.R' __ignored__ [1] => [2] => [3] => R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) --

Comment: Do you have a program called Rscript in C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\R\R-3.5.0\bin\?

Comment: Yes, I do have RScript in the same path. I use the same from cmd prompt and I get answer correctly..

Comment: Try the updated answer - if it still doesn't work let me know

Comment: I get nothing. 
No error message in php error_log file.
my_script.R file creates two files 1.Rdata 2. plot png file
Also I tried to keep this my_script.R file from different folders like Desktop folder, document folders also used C:\wamp64\www\my_script.R.... all produces nothing.... but works fine from cmd prompt. But i need to execute this script from php. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I included 2>&1 at the end of my path and i get this error ARGUMENT '"mypath"\my_script.R' ____ignored____  etc

Comment: Just to confirm: did you recopy the code from my answer? I changed the first path from c:/.../R.exe to c:/.../Rscript.exe/.

Comment: Yes, I tried Rscript.exe from php exec, error said "no file found"... but Rscript.exe - I could use it in cmd prompt and also from R Studio's cmd console. But not from PHP file. There should be a mistake... in Rscript file, do we need to include any commands for cmd prompt? or any Apache configuration? How to debug?

Comment: When I use wrong file or any syntax mistake - i get error "no file found' or syntax mistake error. But when I use correct exec command and file path, I get no error message and no file also has been created either :-(

Comment: Try adding the directory with R and Rscript in it to your PATH variable (google how to do this)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions... Yes I added it and now my script works!!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)